# Where can i find the methods associated with the imagine package ?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have successfully installed **[IMAGINE](https://github.com/orchestral/imagine)**, in my laravel project , now , what i would like to do is USE IT !! , but what i really can't find is , what are the methods that this powerful package has , is there any documentation associated with this package for the methods it provides ? All i  can see on the repository is one example of usage, see below:

```
<?php

use Imagine\Image\Box;
use Imagine\Image\ImageInterface;
use Orchestra\Imagine\Facade as Imagine;

function create_thumbnail($path, $filename, $extension)
{
    $width  = 320;
    $height = 320;
    $mode   = ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_OUTBOUND;
    $size   = new Box($width, $height);

    $thumbnail   = Imagine::open("{$path}/{$filename}.{$extension}")->thumbnail($size, $mode);
    $destination = "{$filename}.thumb.{$extension}";

    $thumbnail->save("{$path}/{$destination}");
}
```

Where can i find more documentation associated with this package or do i have to go thorough the source of this package to understand the methods associated with this package ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: https://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ Search Google for "Imagine docs", and it's the first result.

Comment: @KirkBeard DANM ! thanks .. sometimes i forget the oldest trick in the book !